# Can the FTDI Tx and Rx tension level be different that it's VCC?

Tags: signal, uart, datasheet, ftdi

I'm building my own FT232RL to convert a UART signal to USB.

The source of power will be the USB 5V, but for reasons of the circuit i already have it would be easier to let more of the circuit keep working at 3V3 (i use a DC DC from the 5V to 3V).

The FT232RL needs its VCC at more than +4V so it uses its internal oscillator.

From the datasheet i'm having trouble to understand if i can have its VCC at a voltage level and then receiving the signal on Tx and Rx at a different level, let's say 3V3.

What shall i look on the datasheet?

This is the circuit in question:

[image]

On the datasheet on page 26 there is an example where it shows we can connect VCCIO to the 5V from USB or the 3V3OUT of FT232RL, this is another question i have, instead of 3V3OUT can we use another 3V3? The reason is i don't think 3V3OUT provides enough current for all my circuit. (hope this doesn't cause a problem)

"The VCCIO pin is either supplied with +5V from the USB bus (jumper pins1 and 2 connected), or from the +3.3V output from the FT232R 3V3OUT pin"

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 6.4 has an example circuit with optional 3.3V on the IOs.

Basically just put 3.3V on the VCCIO pin, which sets the level that RX and TX signals run on.

Comment: Hi @TurboJ thanks, reading it, it seems it might work. I provided an image of what i have now. To VCCIO i will have a dc dc convert that converts the 5V of the USB power to the desired 3V3. Hope this works! what do you think? :)

Comment: By the Figure 6.4 it says "The VCCIO pin is either supplied with +5V
from the USB bus (jumper pins1 and 2 connected), or from the +3.3V output from the FT232R 3V3OUT
pin" probably the 3V3 needs to be explicitly the 3V3OUT from the FT232 because i was thinking of using that tension from a 3V3 plane on the board

Comment: datasheet: "+1.8V to +5.25V supply to the UART Interface and CBUS group pins (1...3, 5, 6, 9...14, 22, 23). In USB bus powered designs connect this pin to 3V3OUT pin to drive out at +3.3V levels, or connect to VCC to drive out at 5V CMOS level. This pin can also be supplied with an external +1.8V to +2.8V supply in order to drive outputs at lower levels. It should be noted that in this case this supply should originate from the same source as the supply to VCC. This means that inbus powered designs a regulator which is supplied by the +5V on the USB bus should be used."

Comment: So it does not matter from where the voltage for the IO pins come from. Only that it is referenced to the same potential (i.e. has the same ground) as the FT/USB. Generally speaking VCCIO is always an indication that it is the supply for the "pin bank". As long as one stays within the specification the voltage can come from everywhere.

Comment: Consider possible power sequencing issues if you use an unrelated source